# call stack in visual studio code with out debug/build

Tags: visual-studio-code, callstack

I have very large source code that can run only on Unix.
I am windows guy, so I brought that source code to windows and opened in visual studio code.
I can't build the source due to dependencies, so can't open the debug window.

is there any way to see call stack for the function.
I am looking something, select the function check all the callers.

Comment: depends on your used language, context menu **Goto References**

Comment: @rioV8, goto references, will find all the matches not exact function call, and search return patterns are not that much eye catching, if we get some list purely calls that could be better.

Comment: why not modify the language extension and add this functionality

Comment: It's too difficult to changes the lacks of file extension , i have .h and .c files

Comment: just write a static code analyzer, you can start with the source of a linter or a compiler

Comment: I looing for some extensions, which are already doing above thing you mentioned, 
my aim is to understand the code  better, not develop some tools chains

Comment: yes, but if you need a tool that is not available the quickest way to get it is to make it yourself and not wait till someone else makes it that could take years of waiting